# Add defer to Scripts functions.php

Tags: javascript, php

In my site's `functions.php` script is like

```
add( 'scripts', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js' );
```

which shows on source code like

```
<script src="...jquery.min.js"></script>
```

want to add 'defer' to code like

```
<script src="...jquery.min.js" defer></script>
```

Please anyone guide me to achieve this?

Comment: "functions.php" is something unique to your project. We're not psychic so we don't know what's in it. Where is `function add( $a, $b )` defined?

Comment: you can share `function add {...}`  in functions.php

Comment: I am afraid we have to see add() function's internals. Could be it has a third parameter with some attributes to add to the tags, who knows.

Comment: You should specify in what framework you are trying to run this code, both in text and in tags

Answer (score 0):

By the file `functions.php` I assume that you are using WordPress. To defer loading javascript It's better to use a plugin like `wprocket` or other free variations of optimizer plugins.

But if you want to do it your self you can use below code:

```php
function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) 
    return $url;
if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) 
    return $url;

return "$url' defer ";
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
```

Also if you are not on WordPress CMS you can use a script tag to achieve what you want. In the following code replace defer1.js, defer3.js, and defer3.js, etc. with the link of scripts that you want to defer.

```html
function parseJSAtOnload() {
    var links = ["defer1.js", "defer2.js", "defer3.js"],
        headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        linkElement, i;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        linkElement = document.createElement("script");
        linkElement.src = links[i];
        headElement.appendChild(linkElement);
    }
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", parseJSAtOnload, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", parseJSAtOnload);
}
else {
    window.onload = parseJSAtOnload;
}
```

Comment: @Sam oh okay so then I updated my answer to add the non-WordPress answer. hope it's useful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
add( 'scripts', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" defer="' );
```

So output:

```
<script src="...jquery.min.js" defer=""></script>
```

Comment: Browser reads code like `<script src="...jquery.min.js" defer></script>`

Comment: want this <script src="...jquery.min.js" defer></script>

Comment: The code I entered is the same as what you want. I suggest you examine it carefully.

Comment: Yes absolutely, you should try

Comment: Thanks. Done. Just one query <script src="...jquery.min.js" defer></script> and <script src="...jquery.min.js" defer=""> are same?

Comment: it makes no difference